Are $\phi^{'}_i,\tau_i$ the coresponding compatible functions for equivalence relations constructed in the directed limit of groups/rings.
Background:
The following is taken from: A Graduate Course In Algebra - Volume 1
by: Ioannis Farmakis and Martin Moskowitz,
How to Prove it by: Dan Velleman, and
An Invitation to Abstract Algebra by Steven J. Rosenberg.
Definition 1: Suppose $f:A\to B$ and $R$ is an equivalence relation on $A$, We will say that $f$ is compatible with $R$ if $\forall x\in A\forall y\in A(xRy\to f(x)=f(y))$.
Definition 2:  Let $(I, \preceq)$ be a partially ordered set with the property that for any two elements $i,j$ there is some $k\in I$ such that $i\preceq k, j\preceq k$.
Definition 3:  A directed system of sets (groups, rings, modules, topological spaces, etc.) indexed by $I$ is a collection of sets (rrespectively groups, rings, modules, topological spaces, etc.)  $X_i, i\in I)$, and maps (respectively homomorphisms, contiuous maps, etc.)  $f_{ij}:X_i\to X_j$, defined whenever $i\preceq j$, satisfies the following compatibility conditions:

$f_{ik}=f_{jk}\circ f_{ij}, i\preceq j \preceq k$, and
$f_{ii}=\mathrm{Id}_{X_i}$.

Definition 4:  A direct (or inductive) limit of the directed system of groups $G_i$, is defined by giving a group $G$ and a homomorphism
$$\phi_iG_i\to G$$
for any $i\in I$ such that

if $i<j$ then $\phi_i=\phi_j\circ \phi_{ij}$,

[Note:  the correct partial order should be:  $i\preceq j$.]

if $(G',\phi'_i)$ is another group and family of homormophisms with the same property then there exists a unique homomorphism
$$\phi: G\to G'$$
such that $\phi_i=\phi\circ \phi'_i$ for any $i\in I$.

[Note:  the correct compositional map should be:  $\phi^{'}_i=\phi\circ \phi_i$.  also, if it will make things easiser, the groups can be assumed to be abelian.]
The direct limit can be constructed as the quotient of the subgroup $\oplus_i G_i$ of $\prod_i G_i$ as follows:  $$\varinjlim_{i\in I}G_i=\oplus_i G_i/\sim$$
where, $x_i\in G_i$ is equivalent to $x_j\in G_j$ if and only if
$$\phi_{ik}(x_i)=\phi_{jk}(x_j)$$
for some $k\in I,$ with the additional structure that the product of $x_i\in G_i, x_j\in G_j$ is defined as the product of their images in $G_k$.
Definition 5:
Let $I$ be a partially ordered set such that every pair $\{i,j\}\subset I$ has an upper bound in $I$, and let $\{R_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a collection of rings indexed by $I$.  Suppose that whenever $i,j\in I$ with $i\leq j$, we have a ring homomorphism $\sigma_{i,j}:R_i\to R_j$, and that they homomorphisms are compatible in the sense that whenever $i\leq j\leq k$ we have $\sigma_{j,k}\circ\sigma_{i,j}=\sigma_{i,k}$.  Then a direct lmit of the rings $R_i$ with respect to the maps $\sigma_{i,j}$ is a ring $R$ together with ring homomorphism $e_i:R_i\to R$ such that for every ring $T$ with ring homomorphism $\tau_i: R_i\to T$ compatible with the maps $\sigma_{i,j}$, there exists a ring homorophism $\omega:R\to T$ making the following diagram commute:
$\quad\quad (*)$
Note:  when we say that the $\tau_i$ are compatible with the $\sigma_{i,j}$, we mean that the outer triangle in $(*)$ commutes.
[Note:  I am including Definition 5 along with the commutative diagram, even though the three definitions, 3, 4 and 5 are equivalent, to illustrate what is going on with Definition 3, Definition 4 more clearly.]
Questions:
This is a continuation/continuation of this post.
I am making a new post, because I found another reference that will hopefully help to clarify what I was trying to ask in the other post.  Also, there is a lot of definitions in the other post where here, it is reduced to four different ones.
In Definition 3, Definition 4, to construct the direct limit for gropus,,  an equivalence relation $\sim$ and a quotient set is constructed from it.  From Definition 1, there is the definition of a compatible function $f$ compatible with a given equivalence relation $R$.  So in the case of Definition 3,Definition 4, which function would that be?  From Definition 5, the equivalent definitoin to Definition 3,Definition 4 are given in the context of ring homomorphism.  As one can tell from the attached commutative diagram, there are a lot of maps.  If we match what is given in that commuatibve diagram to the corresponding maps from Definition 3,Definition 4, then here are the corresponding maps along with a table matching domain, ranges, and maps of Definition 1 to the ones from Defintion 4 with Definition 5:
$\sigma_{i,j}=f_{i,j}=\phi_{i,j}, \sigma_{j,k}=f_{j,k}, \sigma_{i,k}=f_{i,k}$,
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& & & &\text{Table} &\\ \hline
\text{Domains, range, maps from Definition }1& A & R & A/R & B &A\to A/R & A/R\to B&A\xrightarrow{f} B  \\ \hline
\text{Definition } 4& G_1,G_j & \sim & G=\varinjlim_{i\in I}G_i=\oplus_i G_i/\sim& G'& \phi_i, \phi_j  &\phi & \phi^{'}_i, \phi^{'}_j \\ \hline
\text{Definition } 5& R_1,R_j & \text{not stated}& R& T& e_i,e_j&\omega& \tau_i,\tau_j \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
What I would like to know is the following: the $f$ in Definition 1, in the context of Definition 4, would that be the maps $\phi^{'}_i, \phi^{'}_j$, that play the role of compatible functions, and the corresponding compatible maps from Definition 5 are $\tau_i,\tau_j$?
Thank you in advance

The point is, once you've constructed the direct limit there will be a natural notion of "compatibility" and the direct limit universally captures this. The $\phi_i,\tau_i$ are not individually compatible maps; rather, the whole thing $(\phi_i:i\in I)$ or $(\tau_i:i\in I)$ - the cocone under the diagram $G_\bullet$ - are analogous to "compatible maps". Definition $1$ isn't directly applicable really. You only use ideas surrounding definition $1$ when you actually prove the direct limit $\bigoplus G_i/\sim$ has the desired universal property

I highly recommend you read Tom Leinster's "basic category theory"

@FShrike when you say that '$\phi_i, \tau_i$ are not individually compatible maps; rather, the whole thing $(\phi_i:i\in I)$ or $(\tau_i:i\in I)$ the cocone under the diagram $G_\bullet$ are analogous to "compatible maps"'.  What did you mean by that?  Also, when you say that I only use ideasa surrounding Definition 1 when I actually prove the direct limit $\oplus G_i/\sim$ has the desired universal property.  Can you elaborate on these two point in an answer if that is possible?  I have Leinster's text section 5.2 infront of me, and I am...

@FShrike ...not seeing the connection of what you are speaking of.  Alsothe reason this was confusing for me, because from the comments i got in this post from
julio_es_sui_glace, he said in two of his response with response one being:  "I don't get what your question is, definition 5 is a definition, there is nothing to construct? Is your question "why the quotient map.....

@FShrike ...$\oplus_i G_i\to \varinjlim_{i\in I}G_i=\oplus_i G_i/\sim$ compatible with the relation of equivalence?", and his response was: "I guess I gave out the answer, when you do a quotient $/$ you have a map $\pi:\to /$ that sends $$ on $[]_$ its class of equivalence. Here $\text{colim }_i$ is the quotient of $\oplus _$ by an equivalence relation, your map is thus the quotient map".  So basically he is saying that the compatible map is the projection map.  Another reason I ask about what the compatible function is suppose to be.....

@FShrike ...is that if you look at an exercise in Dummit and Foote's Abstract algebra text, chapter 7.6 exercise $8 (b)$, it asks the following:  "Let $\bar{x}$ denote the class of $x$ in $G$ and define $\phi_i:G_i\to G$ by $p_i(a)=\bar{a}$.  Show that if each $\phi_{i,j}$ is injective, then so is $\phi_i$ for all $i$ (so we may then identify each $G_i$ as a subset of $G$)." Here I am not sure if the $\phi_{i,j}$ is serving as the compatible function to the equivalence relation $\sim$...

@FShrike ...or if I am suppose to show that $\pi_i$ is suppose to be the said compatible function.  Also, the notion of compatible function is important for proving maps being injective relating to equivalence relations.

What did I mean by that? Well, it doesn't make sense to say "for this $i$, $\psi_i$ is a compatible map". I'm telling you the notion of "compatible" that is relevant here is that of a cocone, which is a family of maps. I recommend you read Leinster's discussion of limits and colimits because from experience and from looking at this question I know the concept confuses you. Maybe a fresh start, looking at a clean, new discussion of the concept, will help

In constructing the direct limit an equivalence relation $R$ can appear, yes. Then stuff from definition $1$ comes into effect; but that's what I said in my first comment. The $\phi_i$ are not "playing the role of compatible functions" and definition $1$ doesn't directly say anything about colimits

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@FShrike I responded to your comment I'm chat.  sorry i just saw this now, I understand we have time zone difference.

I don't think you did? I can't see any new comments, either here or in the chatroom. We should move to the chatroom anyway, this is getting cluttered

@FShrike  I replied asking for some more clarifications.  I think there are still points of confusions for me. I had to break up my replies into chunks since it won't allow me to reply with long messages.
